# Given $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, show that $\operatorname{span}\{f(x-n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is not dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Given any $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, show that the span of $\{f(x-n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is not dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

This problem comes from this presentation with slides [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.406.6401&rep=rep1&type=pdf). It is claimed under the "Remark" section that this set cannot be dense. They actually deal with a more general case but I choose $p=2$ for simplicity.

Since $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is a Hilbert space, then the sequence above being dense in the space is equivalent to the following condition: If we have $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with $(g,f(x-n)) = 0$ (inner-product) for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $g = 0$ (in the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ - sense).

The idea is to find a nonzero $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ that satisfies the hypothesis above. However, I am unable to show this. Is there a simple function that gets the job done?

Thanks :)!

Comment: To be clear, you want the linear span of $\{f(x-n)\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ is not dense, not the set itself, which is trivial as e.g. one of the answers have pointed out, the set is bounded. Neither of the current answers has answered the problem properly.

Comment: This indeed explains my confusion on my (now deleted) comment !  @Justauser Question should be clarified.

Comment: Yup. Also, the paragraph that says " ... is equivalent to ..."  is consistent with @Justauser's correction, and not with the OP's first sentence.

Comment: Sorry about that, yes I meant the linear span of the set!

Comment: My guess would be: use the Fourier transform (or Plancherel transform, unitary on $L^2(\mathbb R)$).  See what the problem becomes after the transform.  Linear combination maps to linear combination; dense maps to dense.  So investigate what the translate by an integer maps to.

Comment: Following citations it seems like the result should be in section 4 of A. Atzmon, A. Olevski,
Completeness of Integer Translates in Function Spaces on R,
Journal of Approximation Theory,
Volume 87, Issue 3,
1996,
Pages 291-327,
ISSN 0021-9045,
https://doi.org/10.1006/jath.1996.0106.
(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021904596901069)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest proof of this doesn't rely on the result you mentioned. Simply look at the Fourier Transform of $f$. Define $e_n(\omega) := e^{2\pi i n \omega}$.

Suppose the span of $\{f(\cdot - n )\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} $ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. After taking Fourier transforms, we have span$\{e_n \widehat{f} \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is also dense. This means that for any $G \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ , we have a sequence of trigonometric polynomials $P_k = \sum_{n \in I_k}a_ne_n$ such that $P_k\widehat{f}$ converges to $G$ in $L^2$.

$L^2$ convergence implies point-wise a.e convergence of a sub-sequence. So replacing $P_k $ with a subsequence, we get that for any $G \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) $, there exists a sequence of trigonometric polynomials $P_k $ such that $P_{k}(x)\widehat{f}(x) \to G(x)$ for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. For this to be true, we must have $\widehat{f}$ nonzero almost everywhere since there are $G \in L^2({\mathbb{R}})$ nonzero a.e.

Let $G = \chi_{[0,1]}$ (Letting $G$ be any function which is $0$ on a sufficiently large set would work). Then $P_{k} \to \chi_{[0,1]}/\widehat{f}$ a.e. implies $P_k \to 0 $ a.e since it's periodic, thereby giving us a contradiction.

Comment: should it be $p_k\widehat f$ instead of $p_k f$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take $a$ such that $$\int_a^{a+1}|\hat{f}(y)|^2dy\ne 0$$ then look at
$g$ such that $$\hat{g}(y)= 1_{y\in [a-1,a]} \overline{\hat{f}(y+1)} -
1_{y\in [a,a+1]} \overline{\hat{f}(y-1)}$$
Using unitary-ness of the Fourier transform we get that
$$\begin{eqnarray}\overline{\langle g,f(x-n)\rangle} &=&\overline{\langle \hat{g},e^{-2i\pi n y} \hat{f}\rangle} \\&=& \int_{a-1}^a 
\hat{f}(y+1) \hat{f}(y) e^{-2i\pi ny}dy-\int_a^{a+1}\hat{f}(y-1) \hat{f}(y) e^{-2i\pi ny}dy\\&=&0\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score -1):

Not a full answer, I leave you to fill details. This idea works for $p \neq 2$ as well.

Suppose that $\mathrm{span} \{ f(x-n) : n \in \Bbb Z\}$ is dense in $L^2(\Bbb R)$. Then you could restrict everything to the domain $[0;1)$ and conclude that the span of $\{ f|_{[0;1)}\}$ is dense in $L^2([0;1))$. This is impossible since a one-dimensional vector space is not dense in $L^2([0;1))$.

For sake of simplicity, let's consider a specific example $f(x)$
$$f(x)= \mathbf{1}_{[0;1)}(x)= \cases{ 1 \qquad x \in [0;1) \\ 0 \qquad \mathrm{otherwise}}$$
A function belonging to the span of $\{ f(x-n)\}_{n \in \Bbb Z}$ has the form
$$\sum_{k=a}^b \lambda_k \mathbf{1}_{[a;a+1)}(x)$$
which is represented by some steps of length $1$.

These are not good to approximate functions which are not constant in the intervals $[a;a+1)$, for example this one
$$g(x)= x \cdot \mathbf{1}_{[0;1)}(x)= \cases{ x \qquad x \in [0;1) \\ 0 \qquad \mathrm{otherwise}}$$

Comment: There's quite a bit wrong with this. In particular the line suggesting that $\{f|_{[0;1} \} $ being a dense one dimensional subspace.